# Django Nested To Do List

Tags: django, django-models

I'm learning Django and I've figured out how to create a model for my task and assign it to a user, but I don't how I can have sub-lists (and sub-lists of sub-lists) underneath

Here is my model:

```
class task(models.Model):

 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 notes = models.TextField()

 created = models.DateTimeField()

 created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

What is the best way to implement lists of lists of lists...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need. First, create your SubList and SubSubList model:

```
class SubList(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    # other fields here

class SubSubList(models.Model):
    sublist = models.ForeignKey(SubList)
    # other fields here
```

Then, lets say you have a Task instance and want to find all of the SubList instances attached to it.  You can just write:

```
task = Task.objects.get(#whatever field you want to lookup by)
sublists = task.sublist_set.all()
```

There are other ways you can achieve this same functionality, but this should be fine for your implementation.

Did that answer your question?

Comment: So it's clear now?  You can also use ManyToManyField if you need to.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I think so. I have to create a model with a foreign key for sub-task -> task and then sub-sub-task -> sub-task (if i wanted 3 levels of tasks). Right?

Comment: So I just read many to many and would it work if I many to many the task model it self? `subtask = models.ManyToManyField(task)`

Comment: Yes that is possible too.  See ManyToManyField.symmetrical and ManyToManyField.through on the link I posted earlier.

Comment: OK, so I got the form working so I can add a task to a task with many-to-many but the VIEW doesnt list the sub-list like. I tried first to get 2 levels working by going `for t in items` then `for t2 in t.subtask` but I got a blank page. Even with the all tag `{% for t in items.all %}<li>{{ t.name }}</li>{% endfor %}` Probably easier than I think but my head hurts and I can't think right now